# POI : duplicate entry: org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/BindigConfig.class

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am having problems to use Poi to read xlsx files in Android. In my gradle I have:

> - compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
> - compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'
> - compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14'

In libs folder I have `xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar`. Previously I had the problem duplicate entry:

> org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/Location.class

but I get to solve with https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XMLBEANS-499

Now, I am getting the error duplicate entry:

> org/apache/xmlbeans/xml/stream/BindigConfig.class

Can somebody help me?

Comment: use one `compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'` or
`compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14'` Then **clean-Rebuild-sync**

Comment: Thanks  IntelliJ Amiya. Now I have removed compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14' line.  But I am getting the error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Add multidex enabled true

Comment: I have multiDexEnabled true and dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

Comment: Ok, IntelliJ Amiya it works, but now I have the problem Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/dropbox/client2/RESTUtility

Comment: From the libs directory in the downloaded SDK, drag the JAR files into your project's app/libs directory. (You'll need both dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar and json_simple-1.1.jar.)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/sdks/android

Comment: I have these jars in my lib folders...this is not the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: There is now a newer version 3.0.1 of XmlBeans provided by the Apache POI PMC which should fix the duplicated classes, this version will be included with the upcoming Apache POI 4.0.0 as well**

There is also a project https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/ which is more actively maintained. It provides a different approach of allowing to use Apache POI on Android via a shaded jar which contains all the required classes in one big jar that can be added to Android projects easily.

---

This is caused by duplicated class-files in the released version of the xmlbeans-jar file. Normal JDKs handle this gracefully, only the Android compiler fails on it.

There is a project which tries to provide fixed jars at https://github.com/andruhon/android5xlsx

Also there is discussion in Apache POI to fix the XMLBeans jar at https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59268 (although it is actually a separate retired ASF-project).